# Regular Expression:How to find such pattern in a string? [x,y]

Tags: regex

I want to find something like [x,y] , (x,y),(x,y],[x,y) ,aka. a number range,x,y are digits.
What would be the right pattern of a regex to deal with it ?Many Thanks.
This pattern in my mind is '[[(][0-9]+,[0-9]+[])]',
but it's not correct in linux grep ,why?

Comment: Do you already have some regex in mind? If so, you may want to share it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
/[[(]\d+,\d+[\])]/g
```

Comment: You got downvoted?  Weird.  Your regex is fine: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?321er

Comment: Firstly, I am not the downvoter :) Secondly, shouldn't you escape the  square bracket and parenthesis as they have special meaning in regex language?

Comment: @Vikdor Yes, but you only need to escape `]` inside `[]`.

Comment: @xdazz I tried your pattern and it failed in egrep in redhat,but this "[[(][0-9]+,[0-9]+[])]" could give me what I want ,I don't know why.

Comment: @GaryGauh If you are using regex in bash, then you need to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, it does not support `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

If whitespace is allowed between the digits, the comma and the parentheses, and floating point and negative numbers are allowed (PCRE regex):

```
/[[(]\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*,\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+))?\s*[\])]/g
```

Group 1 will capture the first number and group 3 the second one.